# pandas pivot_table write to excel outputs empty sheet

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, export-to-excel

It's just so strange.

The pivot_table is definitely not empty. When I print it out it shows everything without problem. But when I try to write it to_excel with ExcelWriter(or just to_excel), it gives me an almost empty sheet(with values only and nothing else).

Here's my code:

```
result = df.pivot_table(
    index=['Client Code','Client Name'],
    values='Fiscal year',
    aggfunc = lambda x: '/'.join(list(set(str(v) for v in x)))
    )

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'resultnew.xlsx',mode='w',engine='openpyxl')
result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Data',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Hopefully there's someone can figure out what is problem.

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample input would have been helpful here.

Comment: Have to point it out that the simple cause of this problem is that pivot_table turns columns inside index=[] into index, and if I add index=False in to_excel, of course it will show nothing in the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out myself. I just need to convert the `pivot_table` `to_records` and turn it to dataframe once again before export it `to_excel`, and the output is perfect.
Simply change the codes like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(result.to_records()).to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Data',index=False)
```